# Path to file won't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am currently trying to get a path to a file to work but it just won't let me.
I'm working on a virtual directory so the path will be dynamic.

this is how my Directories are set up:

WebServices
   ->LiveScanServ.asmx(this is the file I want)

LiveScan
   ->ScanFolders.aspx

My browser Url looks like :http://localhost:43234/dynamicPart/Home.aspx#

inside my ScanFolders.aspx I am making a call to the file LivescanServ.asmx however it just won't find it. This is what I have so far:

```
<Services><asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/LiveScanService.asmx" /></Services>
```

but when I run it, it gives me a 404 error(Not Found).

Any ideas?

edit: this is my javascript for calling ScanFolders.aspx:

```
function loadLiveScanSync() {
$('#centreMenu').slideUp('slow', function () {
    $('#centreMenu').children('div').css('display', 'none');
    $('#loadedContentHolder').load('LiveScan/ScanFolders.aspx');
    $('#loadedContentHolder').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Have  you tried resolving the URL? Or giving it a full path?

Comment: You have a typo. Your file is in `WebService` but your code refers to `WebServices`

Comment: I typed it in wrong here then sorry :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you want is LiveScanServ.asmx. The file you have in your service reference is LiveScanService.asmx. Make sure you can manually resolve your asmx file in the browser, and that the url matches the path in your config.

> WebService ->**LiveScanServ.asmx**(this is the file I want)

```
<Services><asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/LiveScanService.asmx" /></Services>
```